# wget does not download all images

Tags: download, wget

Every day I have to save images from a web page which is updated daily.

To do this I use `wget` command, but unfortunately on about 2000 images I download about 1000 and then it stops.

The command I use is:

```
wget -nc -i URL_DOWNLOAD -P PATH_IMAGE
```

I use `-nc` to ensure that already downloaded images are not re-downloaded again.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What is the error? Is there an error code? See https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html

Comment: Download about? Is it the same number each time? Is it the same volume each time?

Comment: web owner has set a limit on how much traffic a single 'user' may create... ?